# How can I combine (or not) multiple datasets for training a model

Tags: dataset, predictive-modeling

I am trying trying to predict if a customer is likely to [churn](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/churnrate.asp) or not.

I have multiple datasets, from multiple different customers, of which some have churned and some that have not.

I am trying to figure out the best approach to feed the data into the model (XGBClassifier).

1. Combine all the datasets, and add a label (1 if churn, 0 if not), and scale the data collectively of all combined data.
2. Feed the model the separate datasets and scale the data independent of one another.

All the datasets share features, so there is no issue there.

The goal is to have a model where we can feed it a customer, and it will predict if they are likely to churn or not.

Comment: a single customer can't "churn", they can only stop using a business. They definitely can't "chrun," even though that word is used twice in your question.

Comment: @Esther I don't really understand what you mean by this. Before a customer stops using a platform they can definitely display signs that they are soon to stop using it.

Comment: yes, I mean that "churn" is a word to describe *the rate at which customers stop using some business*, not *some individual customer's choice*. Also you misspelled it as "ch*ru*n" instead of "ch*ur*n," which was somewhat confusing when I first read the question.

Comment: Please add more details like dataset sizes, amount of datasets, how datasets for prediction differ from datasets for building a model, maybe some feature statistic. It would give more ground for viewers

Comment: @Esther It's very common to refer to the *churn rate*, which makes little sense if churn is itself only defined as a rate. There are many definitions and practical usages of "churn" that define it at an individual, rather than population level. Churn prediction models are widespread and are designed identify *individuals* at risk of unsubscribing - the goal is not to predict the overall rate at which people leave.